# playing audio/video file from server using list-view in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to list all audio file from my HTTP server to list-view. I am successfully able to do this with below code.

```
class getAudiofromServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ServerFileList.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting File list from server, Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {
                urlAudio = new URL("http://serverlink/folder/uploadAudio");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ApacheURLLister lister1 = new ApacheURLLister();
            try {
                myList = lister1.listAll(urlAudio);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    ServerFileList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    myList);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            mListView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }
```

So to do this i have imported `ivy` Apache external library. Now what i want to do is when user click's on any list item it should play that audio file over there. For that i have implemented this below code.

I have declared

```
    Uri uri;
    URL urlAudio;
    ListView mListView;
    PlaySongAsy play;
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listAudio);
```

and then

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                play = (PlaySongAsy) new PlaySongAsy(myList.get(position)
                        .replace(" ", "%20").trim()).execute();
            }
        });
```

then here is my **PlaySongAsy** class

```
class PlaySongAsy extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        String baseURL;

        public PlaySongAsy(String baseURL) {
            this.baseURL = baseURL;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ServerFileList.this,
                    "    Buffering...", "please wait..", false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    play(baseURL);
                }
            }.start();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

and at last **Play** method.

```
private void play(String baseURL) {
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(baseURL);
        try {
            if (mp == null) {
                this.mp = new MediaPlayer();
            } else {
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
            }
            mp.setDataSource(this, myUri); // Go to Initialized state

            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mp.setOnErrorListener(this);

            mp.prepareAsync();

            // mp.setVolume(5.F, 5.F);

            Log.d("", "LoadClip Done");
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.d("", t.toString());
        }
    }
```

while trying this i am getting error and error is below.

```
02-18 11:49:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(8276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 11:49:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(8276): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.net.URL cannot be cast to java.lang.String
02-18 11:49:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at iqual.fidol_final.ServerFileList$1.onItemClick(ServerFileList.java:72)
02-18 11:49:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:295)
02-18 11:49:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1073)
02-18 11:49:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2577)
02-18 11:49:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3302)
02-18 11:49:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-18 11:49:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-18 11:49:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
02-18 11:49:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
02-18 11:49:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 11:49:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-18 11:49:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
02-18 11:49:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
02-18 11:49:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(8276):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what's the problem you have ?

Comment: @Rakhita, check my error log, i have edited in question.

Comment: What are you getting via the web service, is it a json string?

Comment: @Rakhita, I am not using any web-service. i have used ivy apache library to list all audio files from server.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can directly do this.. myList = lister1.listAll(urlAudio); Becuase my list is a parameterized String list, but lister1.listAll returns just a List...

Comment: @Rakhita, but above statement gives me exact result what i want, i am just not able to play that audio files. That's it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47729/discussion-between-rakhita-and-innocentkiller)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to be sure can we do something like this

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

      String url = null;
      Object o = myList.get(position);

      url = o.toString().replace(" ", "%20").trim();      
      play = (PlaySongAsy) new PlaySongAsy(url).execute();
    }
});
```

Comment: Now it is not giving error but it is not playing audio also means i can not hear any sound.

Comment: What about the log ? If the log has printed anything, that means the Object you are getting is not an String.

Comment: In log i am just getting `java.net.URL` that's it. Nothing else.

Comment: I have edited the answer, please check now, whether it's working... answer

Comment: Glad it helped dude, I removed the instance checking method which used to test what's the type of object. I hope you can do the same in your code.

Comment: Thank you, i will award you this bounty in next 22 hours, because it won't allow me before that.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert you list of songs in php web service to JSON string. Than return that JSON string from web service and parse it back to list of some object and fill the addapter with it.

Comment: It would be hard to get such example that fulfil all you requirements. You should divide this problem into pieces. First search for how to create json string in php. Secondly go for how to invoke php web service from android and then go for how to parse json string in android.